# Outer join in python Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, join, merge

I have two data sets as following

```
A         B
IDs      IDs
1        1
2        2
3        5
4        7
```

How in Pandas, Numpy we can apply a join which can give me all the data from B, which is not present in A
Something like Following

```
B
Ids
5
7
```

I know it can be done with for loop, but that I don't want, since my real data is in millions, and I am really not sure how to use Panda Numpy here, something like following

```
pd.merge(A, B, on='ids', how='right')
```

Thanks

Comment: try instead of `right` you can specify `outer`.

Comment: what is the expected output? The column names seem to be A and B and not IDs ... this is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`NumPy's setdiff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html), like so -

```
np.setdiff1d(B['IDs'],A['IDs'])
```

Also, [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) could be used for the same effect, like so -

```
B[~np.in1d(B['IDs'],A['IDs'])]
```

Please note that `np.setdiff1d` would give us a sorted NumPy array as output.

Sample run -

```
>>> A = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4],columns=['IDs'])
>>> B = pd.DataFrame([1,7,5,2],columns=['IDs'])
>>> np.setdiff1d(B['IDs'],A['IDs'])
array([5, 7])
>>> B[~np.in1d(B['IDs'],A['IDs'])]
   IDs
1    7
2    5
```

Comment: Thank You so much! But despite of my several attempts: "I am receiving error, List indices must be integers not lists"

Comment: @manusharma So, do you have anything else apart from integers in that column of `IDs`, like strings maybe or integers as strings?

Comment: I have two large Lists/ Dataframe, some of them are long, Integers, I tried to use Map(int, dataset) to convert all in one, still the same error List Indices must be integers not lists

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `indicator` and then [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Last you can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `_merge`:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'IDs':[1,2,3,4],
                   'B':[4,5,6,7],
                   'C':[1,8,9,4]})
print (A)
   B  C  IDs
0  4  1    1
1  5  8    2
2  6  9    3
3  7  4    4

B = pd.DataFrame({'IDs':[1,2,5,7],
                   'A':[1,8,3,7],
                   'D':[1,8,9,4]})

print (B)
   A  D  IDs
0  1  1    1
1  8  8    2
2  3  9    5
3  7  4    7

df = (pd.merge(A, B, on='IDs', how='outer', indicator=True))
df = df[df._merge == 'right_only']

df = df.drop('_merge', axis=1)
print (df)
    B   C  IDs    A    D
4 NaN NaN  5.0  3.0  9.0
5 NaN NaN  7.0  7.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the data series to sets and take the difference:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,5,7]})
A=set(df['A'])  
B=set(df['B'])
C=pd.DataFrame({'C' : list(B-A)})   # Take difference and convert back to DataFrame
```

The variable "C" then yields

```
   C
0  5
1  7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use pandas' `.isin()` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,5,7]})
df[~df['B'].isin(df['A'])]
```

If these are separate DataFrames:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'IDs' : [1,2,3,4]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'IDs' : [1,2,5,7]})
b[~b['IDs'].isin(a['IDs'])]
```

Output:

```
   IDs
2    5
3    7
```